# Split screen issue on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur, split-view

I'm using a lot of Split Screen on my new MacBook Pro running on macOS Big Sur but I'm facing a quite annoying visual bug.

Sometimes the split screen separator line stays on the desktop. See a screenshot attached to understand what I mean. The funny thing is that I can drag that line and move it horizontally.
[image: My desktop with the black line]

EDITED: After updating to macOS 11.2.3 (20D91) this bug is still here:
[image: After updating I still have this black line]

EDITED 2: This is how it looks on mission control:
[image]

Comment: Have you rebooted recently? That's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Yes I rebooted. I also updated my computer with the last macOS Big Sur (11.2.3 (20D91)) update and this bar is back.

Comment: What do you see in Mission Control? Can you make a new desktop and close the troublesome one?

Comment: Yes I can make a new desktop and close de troublesome one. I uploaded a new image to show how it looks on mission control

Comment: I believe this seperation line should have been on one of your split screens. so painful a bug, which means on the split screen I lost the seperation line, I cannot adjust the seperation on that screen but I need to go to the main desktop... To check it, moving the seperation line, you will see that the seperation get changed in one of your split screens...